# ios 7 crash with dateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

```
    var dataString = "April 20, 1972" as String
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    // convert string into date
    let dateValue = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dataString) as NSDate!
```

dateValue is nil when run on ios7. This works fine on ios8. How would one go about writing this for ios7

Comment: It doesn't work on iOS8 either.

Comment: See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)  
Also: [Date Field SymbolTable.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format you are specifying (`MM-dd-yyyy`) does **not** match the `String` representing your date.

This code will do the job.

```
let dataString = "April 20, 1972"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
if let dateValue = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dataString) {
    // here you can safely use dateValue
}
```

---

### A few suggestions to make your code more "Swifty"

1. You end you first line with `as String`. This is not necessary infact you are casting a `String` to... well a `String`
2. You are creating a **variable** in your first line. Is that necessary? If the value does not change you should create a **constant** (with `let`). This way the compiler will avoid you to change it unintentionally later. And (I suspect but I am not 100% sure) `let` instead of `var` allows the compiler to do a few optimizations.
3. Same thing for line 2, `dateFormatter` can be a constant.
4. Finally in the last line you are casting `NSDate?` to `NSDate!`. Why? Remember that in Swift every time you resort to this guy `!` you are doing something risky. You should use **conditional unwrap** instead.

These 4 changes are included in my code above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1. Less code is better. 2 & 3, This isn't done for performance but for code safety. Using `let` instead of `var` where applicable is a Best Practice. Quibble: It is not known that there will be any optimization. 4. 100% agree! Definitely do not use explicit unwrapping "!" if there is any, even remote, ever, chance of the the operation returning nil!

Comment: Thanks, I will update my answer to highlight the benefits of using `let` in terms of code safety.